# How to programmatically truncate table in Drupal8

Tags: 8, hooks

I'm wondering how to programmatically truncate a table in drupal8.

Like:

```
db_truncate('some_table');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, the function still exists: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_truncate/8.5.x.

It's deprecated, though, with the advice:

> Instead, get a database connection injected into your service from the container and call `truncate()` on it. For example, `$injected_database->truncate($table, $options);`

If you're not in a context where injection is possible, get it from `\Drupal`:

```
\Drupal::database()->truncate('foo')->execute();
```